# [Phaser]Randomly generated moving elements are being created on the same y plane

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

Edit: I solved my problem and added the relevant code below that made it work

What happens currently is that the initial star spawns at the x location of 800 and the y location of a random number between 325 and 800.  The star then moves to the left at a rate of 1 pixel.  The subsequent stars spawn at a random y value but also spawn at the x position of the first star.  I want the stars to always spawn at the x location of 600 so that they can continue to flow towards the left.  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
 var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var stars;

function preload() {
game.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
}

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    stars = game.add.group();

    stars.enableBody = true;

}

function update() {
createStar();

}

function getRandomArbitrary() {
    return Math.random() * (600 - 325) + 325;
}

//randomly generates star
function createStar(){
        var star = stars.create(800, getRandomArbitrary(), 'star');
        moveIndividual(star);

}


function moveIndividual(moved){
    moved.body.velocity.x = -1000;
}
```

Comment: In your function `createStar()`, you are setting the `x` location to always be `800`. So all your stars will always have `x = 800`. Here's a pretty cool example of randomly generated positions: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/groups/create-sprite-in-a-group

Comment: @philipyoo I want them all to start out on the far right side and have that be the fixed x point of where they start out.  Then as a star spawns I want it to begin to move left

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer and undo your edits, that way people can actually upvote your answer! :)